# Correcting badly formed JSON

Tags: python, json

I need to parse data from a string as JSON. It is currently formatted as

```
data = "{ topic: { name: "foo", other: "bar" }}"
```

I am using the below regex to add quotes to the keys. This works correctly.

```
data_formatted = (re.sub(r"(\w+):", r'"\1":', data_raw))
```

My issue is that sometimes the value contains a semicolon, such as

```
data = "{ topic: { name: "foo", other: "bar:2" }}"
```

Is there away for me to target just the keys when adding quotes and leave the values as is ?
(I have no access to the incoming data unfortunately)

Comment: `data` is not valid python syntax

Comment: Can't really parse it as JSON cause it's not JSON. You'll need a custom parsing function